# How to make function argument that is generic object consuming two functions with one type or void in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have following situation in typescript:

```
type Matcher<T, U> = {
  First: (arg: T) => U,
  Second: () => U
};

class Main<T> {    
  constructor(private value: T) {
  }

  match<U>(matcher: Matcher<T, U>): U {
    return this.value
      ? matcher.First(this.value)
      : matcher.Second();
  }
}

const main = new Main(10);

const res = main.match({ // there is a problem
  First: v => v + 10,
  Second: () => console.log()
});
```

So I have an object that user have to pass to the `match` method of class instance. This object should contain two functions: `First` and `Second`. This functions returns value of one type (e.g. `number`) or of one type + `void` (e.g. `number` + `void`), but nothing else. There cannot be `string` + `number` types.

This code fails with error

```
The type argument for type parameter 'U' cannot be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly. 
Type argument candidat 'void' is not a valid type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate 'number'.
```

I understand why this error happens (`U` is the single type, but functions have two different types and they cannot be merged and so on), but how can I solve this problem? I need:

- strict typing, so there should not be an `any` type
- allow using only one type for both functions or `void` in one or both. `number` and `string` as returning types are not allowed.

Is it possible to do with typescript type system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types):

```
type Matcher<T, U> = {
    First: (arg: T) => U;
    Second: () => U | void
};
```

I added the `void` just to the second function, but you can have it in the first as well.

But you will then need the `match` method to return `| void` as well:

```
match<U>(matcher: Matcher<T, U>): U | void {
    return this.value
        ? matcher.First(this.value)
        : matcher.Second();
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Matcher%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20First%3A%20(arg%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20U%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Second%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20U%20%7C%20void%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass%20Main%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20value%3A%20T)%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20match%3CU%3E(matcher%3A%20Matcher%3CT%2C%20U%3E)%3A%20U%20%7C%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.value%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20matcher.First(this.value)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20matcher.Second()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20main%20%3D%20new%20Main(10)%3B%0A%0Aconst%20res%20%3D%20main.match(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20First%3A%20v%20%3D%3E%20v%20%2B%2010%2C%0A%20%20%20%20Second%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20console.log()%0A%7D)%3B))

---

#### Edit

If I understand you correctly, then this might help:

```
type Matcher<T, U> = {
    First: (arg: T) => U;
    Second: () => U;
};

type MatcherOne<T, U> = {
    First: (arg: T) => void;
    Second: () => U;
};

type MatcherTwo<T, U> = {
    First: (arg: T) => U;
    Second: () => void;
};

class Main<T> {
    constructor(private value: T) { }

    match<U>(matcher: Matcher<T, U>): U;
    match<U>(matcher: MatcherOne<T, U>): U | void;
    match<U>(matcher: MatcherTwo<T, U>): U | void;
    match<U>(matcher: Matcher<T, U> | MatcherOne<T, U> | MatcherTwo<T, U>): U | void {
        return this.value
            ? matcher.First(this.value)
            : matcher.Second();
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Matcher%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20First%3A%20(arg%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20U%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Second%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20U%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atype%20MatcherOne%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20First%3A%20(arg%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Second%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20U%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atype%20MatcherTwo%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20First%3A%20(arg%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20U%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Second%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass%20Main%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20value%3A%20T)%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20match%3CU%3E(matcher%3A%20Matcher%3CT%2C%20U%3E)%3A%20U%3B%0A%20%20%20%20match%3CU%3E(matcher%3A%20MatcherOne%3CT%2C%20U%3E)%3A%20U%20%7C%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20match%3CU%3E(matcher%3A%20MatcherTwo%3CT%2C%20U%3E)%3A%20U%20%7C%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20match%3CU%3E(matcher%3A%20Matcher%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%7C%20MatcherOne%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%7C%20MatcherTwo%3CT%2C%20U%3E)%3A%20U%20%7C%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.value%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20matcher.First(this.value)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20matcher.Second()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20main%20%3D%20new%20Main(10)%3B%0A%0Aconst%20res%20%3D%20main.match(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20First%3A%20(v%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20v%20%2B%2010%2C%0A%20%20%20%20Second%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20console.log()%0A%7D)%3B))

Comment: It still complains that type argument cannot be inferred from usage.

Comment: Added a link to a playground version that complies fine.

Comment: It might be some misunderstanding. I wanted both function in the matcher to be able to be void or same type. So I just added `void` as the second type to the first and the second function, and it failed to compile.

Comment: So it's fine now? Or is there still a problem for you?

Comment: I need an object that allows user to send an object `{ First: void, Second: number }` or `{ First: string, Second: void }` or `{ First: array, Second: array }`, so just enabling `void` on the `Second` or `First` function is not enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134264/discussion-between-lodin-and-nitzan-tomer).